# How to get git up to date on different servers, with individual one-off updates on them?

Tags: git

I have several servers running with the same system, however over time we made several updates locally on each server so that the task was agile. But now we are having a hard time keeping everyone up to date keeping what has been updated locally, taking into account that I changed certain lines of code locally and in the main.

Could someone give me a light?

Comment: This is not a tooling issue as much as it's a process issue. Having changes made directly on servers without going through source control isn't "agile", a better word for it would be "reckless". You need to use a standardized source control platform that all developers use, and then set up processes (ideally automatic, although manual is acceptable in the short term) to roll changes out to your live environments.

Answer (score 0):

Well for your use case I would configure a central gitlab server or so, all servers pull and push to it, it manages the merge/pull requests and keep everything clean and in sync.

If you don't want that, it is possible to sync them, under the condition that all have access to some directory/location/path somewhere, this can act as a central repository so that the other repositories can push/pull to it.

- Let's call this location `/path/to/central`
- clone the repository to that `/path/to/central`
- add this central repository as a remote to the other versions you want to sync, for example if you have a repository on the path: `/path/to/repo1`, then:

```sh
cd /path/to/repo1
git remote add upstream /path/to/central
git checkout -b repo1-changes
git push upstream repo1-changes
```

now you have the changes from repo1 pushed to the central repository:

```sh
cd /path/to/central
git branch -a

# output will look like:
  repo1-changes
* master
```

do the same steps on the other versions you have on the different servers, and come back to the central repository.

All changes are now in a central location and you can merge it the way you like.

After merging everything into `master` on the central repository, go back to the servers an set `master` there to `upstream/master` after fetching it:

```sh
cd /path/to/repo1
git checkout master
git fetch upstream
git reset --hard upstream/master
```

This is a manual process but at the end all master branches should be the same on every server.

hope this helped somehow :)